# Implement IAP in Android without the plugin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've implemented Android's AIDL In-App purchase in an app, only to find out that ([From the docs](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference)):

> AIDL is now deprecated and will be removed in a future release. To
>   implement Google Play Billing features, use the Google Play Billing
>   library.

How can I implement that using Visual Studio in a Xamarin app (without [the plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin))? [The docs for the Google Play Billing Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview) don't lend themselves easily to translation to Xamarin.

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/tree/master/Android/GoogleBillingClient

Comment: @Jason Thanks! That looks good. But how do I use it?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Google.BillingClient/ - it should just be a C# wrapper for the java library, so follow the java docs

Comment: @Jason . Thanks.